# Is there any faster way to insert elements in a std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, vector, insert

I'm trying to insert a string in the following vector: `std::vector<std::string> fileVec`.

The `fileVec` already has many elements in it (up to 1 million strings) before I call these lines:

```
int index = 5;

//there is some code here to find the index i want insert the text (let's take for example has value 5)

fileVec.insert(fileVec.begin() + index, "add this text");
```

The problem I have is that it take so much time to insert the text (specially if index is a small number).

Is there any faster way to add elements in a big vector (without deleting other elements)?

The `fileVec.insert` will not be called many times, around 15 times.

Comment: Inserting at the beginning or middle of a vector is never going to be fast. `std::vector` is not designed to be used like that. It you need to do this often, then you should look for a different data structure, such as `std::list`. Is there a particular reason you are using `std::vector`? Do you have other requirements? How else are you using this `fileVec`? Why do you need to insert at the specific location, i.e. why specifically do you need an ordered vector?

Comment: "_fast way to insert elements in a std::vector_" - maybe - a vector is not what you need. There are options.

Comment: _"std::list is slow, because you need to traverse the entire list until you find the one you want."_
i cant use pointers to access immidiately the element at the index i want?

Comment: Yes you can use pointers to quickly access an element, but you need to be careful. Depending on the container, any operation that invalidates references will also invalidate pointers. `std::list` is probably OK, but `std::vector` definitely isn't.

Comment: Maybe look up rope data structure, it's specifically designed for handling large text and fast manipulation with it. Many text editors use it.

Comment: Are your strings rather large? Are the *n* insertions performed in one step? Are there many random accesses to an element? Generally speaking, *best* solution depends on the use case

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` is not designed for frequent addition of elements in the middle, especially if it is very large (one million elements is huge.) Consider using `std::list` - a double linked list where adding elements in the middle is very fast, because all you have to do is change a few pointers. In `std::vector`, all the elements have to be moved over, which of course, causes lots of overhead.

But at the same time, accessing single elements in `std::list` is slow, because you need to traverse the entire list until you find the one you want.

So pick your poison, but I highly suggest using `std::list` for this case.

Comment: Not only is accessing a specific `list` element slow, traversing elements sequentially will be slower because `list` storage is non-local in memory. So the one cache miss to reach the string content can become two to first access the element and then reach the string. Given a large enough collection the performance reduction *for the common case* can be as much as 50%. So yes, pick your poison, but it depends on the common case most of all, e.g. how often the vector is traversed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your vector is sorted (otherwise you could just add new strings to the end).

What are you doing with this vector? Search? In that case you could keep those 15 new strings in another vector, search in that vector first and if not found - search in original one.